# Scroll through JLabel held in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane that holds a JLabel using the following code:

`//Create TEXT LOG JPanel
        textLogPane = new JScrollPane(logLabel);
        textLogPane.setPreferredSize(textLogPaneDim);
        //textLogPane.setOpaque(true);
        textLogPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        textLogPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);`

The JLabel, logLabel, is represented by a string with an HTML encoding using 
 for carriage returns.  I display certain images based on the contents of certain lines and I would like to be able to scroll the JScrollPane, textLogPane, to show that line whenever I am displaying that graphic.  I know the contents of the line that I want to display but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to scroll down(or up) to the relevant line.

If need be I can change to something other than a JLabel as long as I can keep the HTML encoding and have it look just like multiple lines of text.

Sorry if this is a repeat I tried searching but couldn't find any results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some custom maths and use [scrollRectToVisible()](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) in your viewport. I don't know how to compute the rect of a specific line in your JLabel. A better solution would be to stick your strings into a JList instead, perhaps with a custom renderer for the html, and use

```
list.ensureIndexIsVisible(list.getSelectedIndex());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use "carriage returns" in HTML, you use  "br" tags.

I would suggest you should probably be using a JTextPane for multiline text. I also find it easier to not use HTML, but instead to add strings with attributes. You can also insert icons into a JTextPane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Text Components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for a working example.